# Best approach/alternative to user-defined columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework

I am working on redesigning an old system that relies rather heavily on user-defined additions to data tables.  I would like the ability to use EF or some other ORM mapping framework, so it seems that adding columns to a table is not the best option.

My primary concern is to have a strong database structure and practice in place.  The ORM is secondary and, if necessary, can be eliminated.  Does anyone have an approach that has worked out well for them?

Comment: I like EAV for this specific scenario, but I have absolutely no idea how it fares with EF/ORM. https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/11/19/what-is-so-bad-about-eav-anyway.aspx

Comment: Are you planning you planning to search on any of these user-defined columns, as opposed to simply storing and displaying the data back?

Comment: @AaronBertrand - My only issue with EAV is the current db has 180+ tables, and a majority of them can have udc's.  That said, I have worked out ways to get around the issue of EF and some of the complaints people have with them.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how the number of tables is relevant. If you have 180 tables that all need custom, user-defined columns, how is dealing with that using EAV any worse than whatever other solution you're considering? Why is 180 any worse than 10 or 15 or 45?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight - There is a certain amount of searchability (new word?) that we need.  For example, the user may insert a flag column for filtering purposes.

Comment: In EAV, don't you typically have a one-to-one between EAV tables and original tables?

Comment: If you want to use ORM for dynamic database you need something like EAV to make the real database structure fixed. Otherwise forget about using EF.